# Grep for multiple strings in line, but only print the strings rather than whole line

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am writing a script to read a log file and extract 3 strings from each line (provided they match) then print to an external file, likely CSV or similar.

The format of each log line is in combined Apache access output, as such:

```
%D %v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"
```

Example being:

```
1550606 *user1.testdomain.com* 100.100.100.100 - - *[07/Apr/2015:09:12:48 +0000]* "GET /TestURI HTTP/1.1" 200 11917 "-" *"Test User Agent"*
```

The 3 strings I wish to extract are the virtual host *(%v)*, timestamp *(%t)* and user agent *(%{User-Agent}i)*.

I've tried various combinations of grep and sed but can't figure out quite how I get it to only pull the strings I want, concatenate the output and then print to file.

What would be best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Is your problem matching the formats, returning only the relevant part of the lines, or the concatenation?  Or are you having issues with all the components of the problem?

Comment: Post the expected output format. Also as it is in apache why don't you just get it to write another log in that format  ?

Comment: The format should be output like: resource.domain.com [17/Apr/2015:00:00:00 +0000] "GET /testurl/blah" "Mozilla Firefox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your logs, the `%v` can be easily matched as the second word in each string, you can place the following pattern for sure:

```
^\S+\s(\S+)
```

providing you with the virtual host as the first captured group. The time stamp is enclosed inside square brackets, so it can be matched with:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

leaving only the user agent string to be matched. The user agent is the last string in your logs, enclosed inside double quotations; use the `$` placeholder:

```
"([^"]+)"$
```

Now, combining the 3 sub patterns:

```
^\S+\s(\S+).*?\[([^\]]+)\].*"([^"]+)"$
```

Comment: Which regex dialect is this supposed to be?  Or do you mean `\S` and `\s` instead of `%S` and `%s`?  (Still makes sense to mention that you are using Perl-compatible regex in that case.)